# componentsJoinedByString gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: cocoa, nsmutablearray, exc-bad-access

I have an NSMutableArray i am trying to convert into a string.
Declaring my NSMutableArray...

```
    NSMutableArray *listData;
```

And later inside a method...

```
NSString *foo = [listData componentsJoinedByString:@"|"];  
NSLog(@"%@",foo);
```

It seems no matter what i try i keep getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
To make sure each element in my array was an NSString i also tried this...

```
NSMutableArray *mArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  
for (id ln in listData) {  
    NSString *boo = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",ln];  
    [mArray addObject:boo];  
}  
NSString *foo = [mArray componentsJoinedByString:@"|"];  
NSLog(@"%@",foo);
```

I can manipulate my NSMutableArray by adding/deleting objects in the same method or other methods inside my class. But when i try "componentsJoinedByString" the error pops up. Does anyone have any advice or another way i can combine this array into a single NSString?

Comment: How/where are you creating and populating `listData`?

Comment: In my class header file i am declaring the property listData. @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *listData; In my .m file i am synthesizing it and releasing it. I populate the list through another method called loadList which gets it's data from a stored plist file. "NSMutableArray *tmpList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];return tmpList;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you've given, there will never be an `NSMutableArray` for `listData`. At some point in your code, you'll need to create one, and presumably populate it.

**Edit**
Okay, so you may get into memory management problems here, so let's be a bit clearer:

You're synthesizing getters and setters for the instance variable, so it's good practice to use those to access it, they'll take care of retain and releasing appropriately.

To set `listData` you can simply use

```
self.listData = [listManage getList:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"list_name"] list:@"LIST"];
```

or

```
[self setListData:[listManage getList:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"list_name"] list:@"LIST"]];
```

if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks Paul! So in my class loadView i added "NSMutableArray *listData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];"
before i populated my list with "listData = [listManage getList:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"list_name"] list:@"LIST"];" This fixed the problem. Although i get a local declaration hides instance variable warning. I hate being a newbie, still trying to fully understand how to create a NSMutableArray accessible by my entire class. (not enough reputation points to upvote your answer but again thanks!)

Comment: You can mark it as correct if you like though! ;-) If you have listData as an instance variable, then you can just use `listData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

Comment: and the lightbulb goes 'ding'!