# componentsJoinedByString causing crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm pretty sure this is eactly the same problem as in [componentsJoinedByString gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315331/componentsjoinedbystring-gives-me-exc-bad-access)

basically, an array is populated using this code, with ARC turned on:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getArrayOfCommaSeparatedSelectorStrings{
    NSMutableArray *Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(NSMutableArray *e in [self getArrayOfSelectorArrays]) {
        [Array addObject:[displayCSSInformation returnArrayAsCommaList:e]];
    }
        return Array;
}
```

and then displayCSSInformation tries to return a comma separated list with this method :

```
+(NSString *)returnArrayAsCommaList:(NSMutableArray *)ToBeConverted{
    NSString *test = [ToBeConverted componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
    return test;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you set an exception breakpoint to see where the crash is occurring?

Comment: Yes to both of these. Exception is occurring where the componentsJoinedByString happens.

Comment: Really should say you're using ARC In the question body. Edited.

Comment: If `returnArrayAsCommaList:` is a class method, then `displayCSSInformation` is a class. By convention, class names in Objective-C are written in `UpperCamelCase`, and variables and method names are written in `lowerCamelCase`. This doesn't fix your problem but will help others who try to read not just this excerpt of code but your entire program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's usually no need to use a separate method if all that method does is invoke another method. Remove your `+returnArrayAsCommaList:` method and just use `componentsJoinedByString:` on the array directly.

```
- (NSMutableArray *) getArrayOfCommaSeparatedSelectorStrings
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSMutableArray *e in [self getArrayOfSelectorArrays])
        [array addObject:[e componentsJoinedByString:@", "]];

    return array;
}
```

The above should work (it works in my small test example), if you are still getting errors:

1. Make sure that `getArrayOfSelectorArrays` is actually returning an array of array of strings. Log the output to the console or step through with a debugger.
2. Use the “Build & Analyze” option to have the static analyser check for any issues. This is less of an issue with ARC but it will still pick up things such as using uninitialised values.
3. Make sure you have properly bridged ownership from any Core Foundation objects.